# Create icosahedron in VTK

Tags: vtk, point-cloud-library

I'm trying to debug a section of code from the Point Cloud Library.
It's using VTK to create an icosahedron.

I've pasted the offending code into a new function – the code between the `\\ *** ... ***` comments is copied directly from PCL. I added the input and output sections:

```
int main()
{
  int tesselation_level_ = 2;

  // *** begin PCL code ***

  vtkSmartPointer<vtkPlatonicSolidSource> ico = vtkSmartPointer<vtkPlatonicSolidSource>::New ();
  ico->SetSolidTypeToIcosahedron ();
  ico->Update ();

  //tesselate cells from icosahedron
  vtkSmartPointer<vtkLoopSubdivisionFilter> subdivide = vtkSmartPointer<vtkLoopSubdivisionFilter>::New ();
  subdivide->SetNumberOfSubdivisions (tesselation_level_);
  subdivide->SetInputConnection (ico->GetOutputPort ());

  // Get camera positions
  vtkPolyData *sphere = subdivide->GetOutput ();

  // *** end PCL code ***

  std::cout << "Sphere points: " << sphere->GetNumberOfPoints () << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Sphere polys: " << sphere->GetNumberOfPolys () << std::endl;
}
```

I expected that the sphere created from the subdivided icosahedron would have some points and some polygons, but the output seems to show that the sphere is in fact empty:

```
! ./test
Sphere points: 0
Sphere polys: 0
```

Am I doing something obviously wrong?
How can I create a icosahedron?

(This is with VTK 5.10 on OSX 10.9)

Answer (score 0):

Look at [VTK meshes subdivision example](http://www.paraview.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/Meshes/Subdivision). In the example after set the input for the subdivisionFilter object a call for update is made. In your code `subdivide->Update();` after set the input connection of subdivide